# How would you abstract this series of list continue conditions?

Tags: python, iteration

I have some source code that has a number of conditions that would lead to skipping the rest of the current list iteration:

```
for name, row in recent.iteritems():
    if name in ignore:
        print name + "is on ignore list. Skipping."
        continue

    if number_of_open_orders_in(name) == max_orders_per_market:
        print name + "has max number of open orders. Skipping."
        continue

    if row[0].ask < 100e-8:
        print name + "is a single or double satoshi coin. Skipping."
        continue

    gain.append(
        (
            name,
            percent_gain(row[0].ask, row[1].ask),
            row[1].ask,
            row[0].ask,
            'https://bittrex.com/Market/Index?MarketName={0}'.format(name),
        )
    )
```

As you can see, the code is very regular. Each reason for skipping

1. performs a test as a function of `row` or `name`
2. If the test returns `True`,

   - print a message
   - skip the current loop iteration

Comment: And where is the code?

Comment: What do you mean with abstraction? Do you just want input on the structure (i.e. if we would write it differently) or are you looking for something else?

Answer (score 0):

The following is the code with the redundancy removed:

```
for name, row in recent.iteritems():
    if name in ignore:
        print name + "is on ignore list. Skipping."

    elif number_of_open_orders_in(name) == max_orders_per_market:
        print name + "has max number of open orders. Skipping."

    elif row[0].ask < 100e-8:
        print name + "is a single or double satoshi coin. Skipping."

    else:
        gain.append(
            (
                name,
                percent_gain(row[0].ask, row[1].ask),
                row[1].ask,
                row[0].ask,
                'https://bittrex.com/Market/Index?MarketName={0}'.format(name),
            )
        )
```